# Elasticsearch Autocomplete on Specific field in Specific Document

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, n-gram

I have Documents that contain many fields which are lists of values.
I would like to be able to autocomplete from one specific such field at a time in one specific document **without data duplication** (like [Completion Suggestors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html))

For example, I would like to be able to autocomplete after 3 characters from the values in the `category` field of the document with `id: '7'`.

I tried to implement something based on [this](https://qbox.io/blog/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch) but this doesn't seem to work on a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering the suggestions by a field, you can add the fields to filter on in [context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html).

```
 "category":{
        type: "completion",
        payloads: false,
        context: {
            id: {
                  type: "category",
                  path: "id"
            }
        }
   }
```

You can index the document as :

```
POST /myindex/myitem/1
{
    id: 123,
    category: {
        input: "my category",
        context: {
            id: 123
        }
    }
}
```

The minimum length check has to be applied on the client side. ES suggesters do not provide anything like that.

Now, you can suggest on `category` field with a filter on `id` field.